# How do I get an editable div in a WebView to behave correctly?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a WebView, whose html page contains an editable div. On Jelly Bean, all is good. However on Ice Cream Sandwich, I'm seeing the following:-

1. when focussed, the div has a brown border
2. when typing, when I touch the Enter key, the following happens

   1. I get a double audio, ie. I get a tick for the key press, followed by a ping as for a touch event
   2. The div flashes brown
   3. The onscreen keyboard disappears
3. I can do a long press to invoke select/cut/copy mode. However whatever I do, I can't get the Paste button to appear
4. I have found that if I touch outside the editable div, such that the div loses focus and the brown border disappears, that I can carry on typing into the div, and now, pressing enter works as expected.

Since all of this works fine on Jelly Bean, I'm guessing it's an ICS issue. However, since I need to support ICS, I'm looking for any suggestions to work around this behaviour.

There is nothing remarkable in the code...

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.addJavascriptInterface(javascriptObject, "injectedObject");
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/pageWithEditableDiv.html");
webView.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [BTAndroidWebViewSelection library](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection)?

It seems to solve the exact problem you are having.

According to the docs, you just need add the following imports to your HTML page:

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='rangy-core.js'></script>
<script src='rangy-serializer.js'></script>
<script src='android.selection.js'></script>
```

All the scripts can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection/tree/master/assets).

Comment: I've taken the decision to withdraw my app from 4.0 devices and below. So I won't be testing this answer, and so can't accept it. Many thanks anyway for the suggestion - bounty awarded.